# Is simple module over commutative ring always a field?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

M is a simple module if and only if $M\cong R/I$ for some I maximal ideal in R. If $R$ is commutative, can I say M is a field? I'm confused about this fact because when proving it I use the fact that M is field... But then why call it module?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$M$ is *module* isomorphic to $R/I$, but that doesn't mean it has suddenly become a field.

Now, you can treat the module $M$ as a ring by transferring the structure of $R/I$ back to $M$ through the bijection, but until you do that, $M$ does not have any binary multiplication operation, and hence it does not make any sense to call it a field (or a ring.)

Comment: I'm still confused--why can I treat $M$ as a ring by transferring the structure of $R/I$ if it's not actually a ring?

Comment: $R/I$ certainly has a ring structure. If $\phi:R/I \to M$ is any bijection, and $m,n\in M$, you can define $m+n:=\phi^{-1}(\phi(m)+\phi(n))$ and $mn:=\phi^{-1}(\phi(m)\phi(n))$, and these operations make $M$ into a ring.

Comment: @Vladimir Said another way, $M$ certainly isn't a ring until you define a multiplication on it. You can achieve that in the way I described, by declaring the module homomorphism to be a ring homomorphism by fiat. This is not very generally interesting, though.

Comment: But after defining this multiplication in $M$, why doesn't this make $M$ a field? Still confused about the logic...

Comment: @Vladimir It *does* make it a field. I've said that at least three times. But the point is that this structure on $M$ is not very important and not very useful. Being isomorphic as modules is more natural and useful.

Answer (score 5):

The natural thing to say is that $M$ becomes a vector space of dimension$~1$ over the field $K=R/I$. Of course any such vector space is isomorphic *after choosing a basis* to $K^1$, which can be identified in an obvious way with $K$ itself (so you can equip $K^1$ with an internal multiplication and it becomes a field). However this does involve the choice of a single basis vector (which then becomes the neutral element for multiplication), and different choices give different field structures on$~M$. So it would be confusing to say that $M$ is a field, though it can be made into a field in various ways.

The main point here is that being isomorphic does not mean having a canoncial isomorphism at hand.